# How to unpin preinstalled apps from the start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I remember there being a script for unpinning preinstalled apps from the start menu but I can't find it. Is there any way to remove these entries from the start menu? Examples of this include the calculator or the Nvidia Control Panel. give me some clear instruction how to remove these from the list in start. Ideally some Powershell script. Or pont me to the loaction in the registry.(If that works.)

Additional information:

This is about the start menu not about the autostart nor about the taskbar. I am also not talking about the tiles to the right of the start menu. I am talking about the list that shows up when you click on start. You know the one that sorts things alphabetically.

I have already checked
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
as well as
`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
there are no shortcuts to these unwanted entries there. **So please do not point me there.**

I do not want to remove these apps entirely. I just don't want shortcuts to these in my start menu. I know these entries disappear when you uninstall them using things like CCleaner but thats not what I am looking for.

As I said, I remember there being a script you could paste into Powershell to remove preinsalled apps from the start menu but I think it stopped working after a certain update. Can't test that though, since I cant find it. I think it was made by a german user on this forum in 2018 but I might be wrong. If someone knows what I am talking about please let me know.

And last but not least: I know this is a petty thing to worry about. But I like my start menu clean since I run everything from there instead of using desktop shortcuts.